# Azure Function App Cosmos DB trigger connection drop

Tags: azure, azure-function-app

I am using a Function app with cosmos DB trigger, when running locally, the behavior is very strange as I stop receiving events randomly, like if the connection to the Lease collection drops. I am getting an error message that says a read operation fails to Blob storage, but not sure if this is related. Here's the error:

```
There was an error performing a read operation on the Blob Storage Secret Repository. 
Please ensure the 'AzureWebJobsStorage' connection string is valid
```

I am running the function app with this code: `func host start --cors * --verbose`

And here's the CosmosDBOptions object I can see in the console:

```
[2021-02-09T16:17:58.305Z] CosmosDBOptions
[2021-02-09T16:17:58.307Z] {
[2021-02-09T16:17:58.307Z]   "ConnectionMode": null,
[2021-02-09T16:17:58.308Z]   "Protocol": null,
[2021-02-09T16:17:58.309Z]   "LeaseOptions": {
[2021-02-09T16:17:58.310Z]     "CheckpointFrequency": {
[2021-02-09T16:17:58.310Z]       "ExplicitCheckpoint": false,
[2021-02-09T16:17:58.311Z]       "ProcessedDocumentCount": null,
[2021-02-09T16:17:58.311Z]       "TimeInterval": null
[2021-02-09T16:17:58.312Z]     },
[2021-02-09T16:17:58.313Z]     "FeedPollDelay": "00:00:05",
[2021-02-09T16:17:58.313Z]     "IsAutoCheckpointEnabled": true,
[2021-02-09T16:17:58.314Z]     "LeaseAcquireInterval": "00:00:13",
[2021-02-09T16:17:58.314Z]     "LeaseExpirationInterval": "00:01:00",
[2021-02-09T16:17:58.315Z]     "LeasePrefix": null,
[2021-02-09T16:17:58.316Z]     "LeaseRenewInterval": "00:00:17"
[2021-02-09T16:17:58.316Z]   }
[2021-02-09T16:17:58.323Z] }
```

and my host.json file:

```
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensionBundle": {
    "id": "Microsoft.Azure.Functions.ExtensionBundle",
    "version": "[1.*, 2.0.0)"
  }
}
```

Finally, that issue started since I added a shared folder, not sure if it's related but it's really annoying, deleting leases collection solves temporary the problem but It costs a lot of time and all the other running functions break because I clean all the collection.

Comment: This error is not related to Cosmos DB Trigger, but rather to the Functions runtime depending on the Azure Storage service for internal operations. The Cosmos DB Trigger has no dependency nor accesses any storage account. Deleting the leases collection is probably not related to the fix but rather the fact that you restart the Function. CosmosDBOptions are not really relevant, what matters in the case of the Trigger is the configuration in the Trigger itself.

Comment: Might be related to https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-js/issues/211#issuecomment-671580227, are you configuring the `AzureWebJobsStorage` correctly to point to the Storage account or the Emulator?

Comment: I am not configuring the AzureWebJobsStorage correctly, I thought Azure Storage is not a dependency for local development. I am trying to use the emulator and will update you on this

Comment: @MatiasQuaranta configured the `AzureWebJobsStorage` to an Azure Storage but still it worked the first time and then.. `Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000xxxxxxxx'` Its very weird because 1/2 function is working. Found that article on Google that recommends rebooting the system LOL https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/165592/host-lock-lease-acquired-by-instance-id-3900000000.html

Comment: Tried rebooting, problem still here.. How do I get the Trigger configuration ? Now no function is triggered

Comment: I honestly do not know the source of the problem on Functions, just that it's not related to the Trigger. The Trigger configuration is what is in your Function code https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2-trigger?tabs=csharp#configuration, but this is not related to your error with the Storage service.

Comment: @FrankGong which one ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TLDR; Using the CosmosDB emulator for local development solves this issue, as you won't have two functions pointing to the same lease collection.**

There are two important points:

1. If you have one Azure Function deployed on Azure and one running locally in your machine with the **same lease configuration listening for changes in the same monitored collection** then these will behave as multiple instances of the same deployment and changes will be delivered to one or the other and you might experience "event loss" on the one running in Azure. This is documented in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/troubleshoot-changefeed-functions#some-changes-are-missing-in-my-trigger. If you want to have 2 independent Functions listening for changes in the same monitored collection, sharing the same lease collection, you need to use the `LeaseCollectionPrefix` configuration https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-create-multiple-cosmos-db-triggers
2. The error you are seeing locally is potentially related to either not having the Azure Storage emulator running or not configuring the `AzureWebJobsStorage` configuration locally to use it. Azure Functions runtime (regardless of the Cosmos DB Trigger) requires a storage account. You can use `UseDevelopmentStorage=true` for the local storage emulator.

Comment: I am in the first point, setting a `LeaseCollectionPrefix` fixed the problem but isn't a good option, because it's defined in the function level, and if I deploy it. The deployed version will point to that prefix, and I then will need to change again my preffix locally, which is not very consistant.. Makes sense ?

Comment: You can use a Prefix that is based in a configuration, like `%Environment%`, so when it's in Azure, you have a Function App setting for Environment = Azure and when running locally, you can have a setting in your appSettings.local.json that sets it to Local.

Comment: Ideally, if you are local, you'd end up using a dev environment which is different than the production environment, not hooking to the prod collection/account. But if that is not possible, then having alternate configurations should be the way forward.

Comment: If costs are an issue, you can always have your lease collections inside a database with Shared Throughput, so you have either 2 lease collections (one for prod, one for dev) and you point dev to the second one, or you end up using 2 lease prefixes. Both will have the same cost.

Comment: Umm. well no, it's not a cost issue, I think it's a design issue, if I have a cosmosDB emulator running locally, can I have the function be trigerred by the local cosmosDB collection ?

Comment: I tried with the local emulator, it's working as expected, can you edit your answer and add that point (using a local cosmosDb emulator), for the community. Huge thanks for your guidance.